# Definite double integral in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am a beginner in *Mathematica*. I want to perform the following definite double integral equation in *Mathematica* and want to compare the solution with mine.

$$
A_{P-A} = R^2\int_{\theta=\frac\pi2-\beta}^{\alpha_\text{eq}}\int_{\phi=\arcsin(1/\tan\beta\tan\theta)}^{\pi-\arcsin(1/\tan\beta\tan\theta)}\sin\theta\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\phi
$$

$$
A_{P-A} = \pi R^2(1-\cos\alpha_\text{eq})+2R^2\left[\cos\alpha_\text{eq}\arcsin(\cot\beta\cot\alpha_\text{eq})-\arctan\frac{\cos\beta}{\sqrt{\sin^2\beta-\cos^2\alpha_\text{eq}}}\right]
$$

I wrote the command by following *Mathematica* tutorial for the integral and it is not showing any result and keep running for over 2 hours. Am I making any mistakes?

```
R^2 Integrate[
  Sin[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], (Pi/2), \[Alpha] }, {\[Phi], 
   ArcSin[1/(Tan[\[Theta]]*Tan[\[Beta]])], 
   Pi - ArcSin[1/(Tan[\[Theta]]*Tan[\[Beta]])]}]
```

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Here I made the edit.

Comment: Maybe the `GenerateConditions -> False` option will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(leaving out the global $R^2$ multiplier)

First step: definite integration over φ:

```
A = Integrate[Sin[ϑ], {φ, ArcSin[1/(Tan[ϑ]*Tan[β])], 
      Pi - ArcSin[1/(Tan[ϑ]*Tan[β])]}] // FullSimplify
```

> 2 ArcCos[Cot[β] Cot[ϑ]] Sin[ϑ]

Second step: indefinite integration over ϑ:

```
B[β_, ϑ_] = Integrate[A, ϑ, GenerateConditions -> False] // FullSimplify
```

> (lengthy output)

Third step: insert integration boundaries. I think that here's the tricky bit that stumps the automatic integration you've been running for hours. Manually taking the limit at the lower boundary (implicitly assuming that $\pi/2-\beta<\alpha$):

```
J[α_, β_] = B[β, α] - Limit[B[β, ϑ], ϑ -> π/2 - β, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
```

> (lengthy output)

Here's a numerical example to suggest that this result gives the same answer as a numeric integration and as your result formula:

```
With[{α = 1.3, β = 0.3},
  {J[α, β], 
   NIntegrate[2 ArcCos[Cot[β] Cot[ϑ]] Sin[ϑ], {ϑ, π/2 - β, α}],
   π (1 - Cos[α]) + 2 (Cos[α] ArcSin[Cot[β] Cot[α]] - ArcTan[Cos[β]/Sqrt[Sin[β]^2 - Cos[α]^2]])}]
```

> {0.0170522 - 6.66134*10^-16 I, 0.0170522, 0.0170522}

Comment: The OP's integral looks awfully like the volume of a sphere slice, so I'm not sure about your divergence claim.

Comment: Yes I think I managed to confuse myself here...

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less Yes it is to calculate segment area of a sphere that I posted here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3124391/surface-area-of-a-sphere-segment .